# iOS: What kind of tool did this guy use to prototype this demo?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, user-interface, demo

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVbuk3jizGM

---

http://matthaeuskrenn.com/new-car-ui/

I'm trying to figure out what kind of tool did this guy use for creating this demo. 
Did he create this using xCode and pure objective-c? I searched around but I didn't find anything that gave me a hint.

My first instinct tell me that everything is written natively but I'm not familiar with iOS Development so I'm not sure if there is some kind of tool to create this kind of interactions/animations and then port them to the iPad/iPhone.

Any hint?

Edit: I wrote to the guy. But since the video went viral, probably he has too many emails and too little time.

Comment: Your answer is probably just an email away: mattkrenn@gmail.com

Comment: I wrote to him. But since the video went viral, probably he has too many emails and too little time.

Comment: No way to tell. There are infinitely many technologies that could produce this result.

Comment: Judging by the demo that you can use on his site it is pure html5

Comment: I would assume he used objective-c because animations / movements are very smooth -- something you may not achieve with an html solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tweeted to the creator and I finally have an answer. As someone suggested, he indeed created everything in HTML/CSS and Javascript, but I'm impressed how smooth is the final result. I didn't expected that performance for an HTML, JS implementation.

Anyways, if anyone was interested in this, the answer is HTML, CSS and Javascript.